# why does certbot still can generate my certs after wipe?

Tags: linux, docker, letsencrypt, certbot

i tested some things in docker and f*d up, also removed all containers and volumes including the certbot ones.
so why is certbot still able to give me my certificates back?

is it because they are stored somewhere in a web storage?

is it because dockers storage driver keeps files even after deleting volumes/containers?

is it because letsencrypt only needs a succesful DNS challenge and nothing more?

i'm just curious how it works..

---

Addressing comments:

> What do you mean by "give ... certificates back"? Are you sure it's not just generating a new certificate?

with "give certs back" my thinking was, that i actually would need more than just my mail and dns possession.

does this imply i don't need to back up the letsencrypt certificates and instead create new ones? what is the minimum requirement to "overwrite" then? thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean by "give ... certificates back"? Are you sure it's not just generating a new certificate?

Comment: You can check whether it generates new certificates by putting your domain name into the certificate transparency registry form: https://crt.sh/ . By default it will regenerate certificate every other month (leaving a month of a headroom). If you them generated more often, those were all newly generated certificates.